# What to do with the logic ahead

Tags: c

Write a C program to read a 4 digit number from user. If sum of first and second digit is equal to multiplication of third and four digit then terminate the program and display sum of digits of number otherwise continue reading number and add current number to previous input sum

So far what I know is logic to get 3rd n 4th digit 
I. E. 
n%10 and n/=10 but how can I get 1st and 2nd digit

Comment: Hint: If you divide a 4 digit number by 10 in integer division then you end up with a 3 digit number, and so on.

Comment: Do you really understand the logic to get the 3rd and 4th digit? Because it's the same logic for the rest.

Comment: An alternative approach is not to use maths but rather to use string parsing. Read the input in as a string and then convert each character to a digit.

Comment: Means I have to put that division in loop?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
int main()
{
    int n, t, multiplicate = 1,sum=0, remainder, cnt=0;
    printf("Enter an integer\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    t = n;
    while (t != 0)
    {
         remainder = t % 10;
         t = t / 10;
         cnt = cnt+1;
         if(cnt<=2)
         {
              multiplicate = multiplicate * remainder;
         }
         else
         {
             sum = sum + remainder;
         }
    }
    printf("multiplicattion of last two digits = %d\n", multiplicate);
    printf("sum of first two digits  = %d\n",  sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Compare sum and multiplication if both are equal then terminate it and display it. ```if(sum==multiplicate){//do something and break;}```

Comment: But break can be used only in loops?

Comment: its common sense, you may use exit or none.

Answer (score -1):

Here you are.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    const int Base = 10;

    int n = 1234;

    for ( int divisor = 1; divisor <= n ; divisor *= Base )
    {
        printf( "%d ", n / divisor % Base );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
4 3 2 1
```